# SQL Server BETWEEN and OR Statement

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I want to use 2 clauses in SQL Server like so:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date_time ASC) AS RowNumber,
       <column_name1>,
       <column_name2>,
       <column_name3>, 
       date_time 
from <table name>
where <column name1> = 'assdf'  
   or RowNumber between 1 and 10
```

But this produces an error. What is wrong with this query?

Comment: )AS RowNumber I think there should be a space before AS->     ) As RowNumber

Comment: Why use Row_number since you need 1-10 rows,`select top 10 * from table where <column_name1>='assdf' order by date_time asc`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [CTE expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) :

```
with cte as
       (    
         SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY date_time ASC)AS RowNumber, 
                <column_name1>,
                <column_name2>,
                <column_name3>, 
                date_time from <table name> 
       )
select * from cte where <column name1> = 'assdf' or RowNumber between 1 and 10
```

Comment: do you just need rows 1 to 10 ..? then `select top 10 * from table where <column_name1>='assdf' order by date_time asc` try this..

Answer (score 0):

```
with Temp as
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY date_time ASC)AS RN, 
       <column_name1>,
       <column_name2>,
       <column_name3>, 
       date_time 
       from <table name>
       where  <column name1> = 'assdf'
)
SELECT * FROM Temp where RN BETWEEN 1 and 10
```

**OR**

```
SELECT  <column_name1>, 
        <column_name2>,
        <column_name3>,
        date_time FROM
        (
       SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY date_time ASC)AS RN,
             <column_name1>,   
             <column_name2>,
             <column_name3>,
             date_time 
             from <table name>
             where  <column name1> = 'assdf'
        ) As S

WHERE RN BETWEEN 1 and 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reference `RowNumber` column in the same query, rather reference it in outer query. Try this:

```
select * from 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date_time ASC) AS RowNumber,
      <column_name1>,
      <column_name2>,
      <column_name3>, 
      date_time
      from <table name>
) tab
 where <column name1> = 'assdf' or
       RowNumber between 1 and 10
```

Answer (score 0):

this will help

```
select * from 
   ( 
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY date_time ASC)AS RN,
           <column_name1>,
           <column_name2>,
           <column_name3>,
           date_time
           from <table name>
           where  <column name1> = 'assdf'
   ) 
 where RN between 1 and 10
```